# Get Facebook application subscribers

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's suppose I have a Facebook application with ID: XXXXXX

Is there a way to get its subscribers who are already in my friends list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an FQL query like this:

```
SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE 
  uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
  AND is_app_user = 1
```

You can only get this information from a user who is currently authenticated with your app.